# Swift - protocol as type as target of button action

Tags: swift, uibutton, protocols

I am trying to create - HeaderView which is subclass of UIView, it contains a close button and a title label.

```
class HeaderView: UIView {
    private var titleLabel: UILabel!
    private var closeButton: UIButton!
}
```

I don't want to add self as target of closeButton action but want to set myViewController as its target, moreover I want HeaderView class to be reusable.

So I declared a protocol:

```
protocol CloseViewProtocol {
    func closeViewAction(sender: UIButton!)
}
```

And declared a variable like this:

```
class HeaderView: UIView {
    private var titleLabel: UILabel!
    private var closeButton: UIButton!

    var closeButtonTarget: CloseViewProtocol?
}
```

to enforce (at compile time) that closeButtonTarget implements closeViewAction: method.

Now I can't do this:

```
closeButton.addTarget(closeButtonTarget, action: "closeViewAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

doing which compiler complains -

```
Cannot convert value of type 'CloseViewProtocol?' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'
```

To resolve this I can do this:

```
let buttonTarget = closeButtonTarget as! UIViewController
closeButton.addTarget(buttonTarget, action: "closeViewAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Is there any better way to achieve expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Andrius approach, but to answer the question, you have to add the `class` keyword to your protocol’s inheritance list:

```
protocol CloseViewProtocol: class {
    func closeViewAction(sender: UIButton!)
}
```

Comment: @RichardTopchiy Yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old school - protocol delegate, new patterns are more functional programming
I would suggest using closures

```
var closeHanlder:()->Void?
```

Then have button as private var inside, and in View Controller do

```
headerViewInstance.closeHandler = self.handleCloseFunction
```

I should add that the button action gets handled in the headerView, whose action does what it needs and calls closeHandler?()