# Swift: Protocol method as Action in target-action

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, delegation, target-action

I'd like to have a protocol:

```
protocol CameraButtonDelegate: class {
    func cameraButtonDidPress(_ sender: UIButton)
}
```

So, I could assign any client to a button, e.g.:

```
cameraButton.addTarget(delegate, action: #selector(cameraButtonDidPress), for: .touchUpInside)
```

However, it does not compile as I have to specify a particular function in `action`, e.g.:

```
cameraButton.addTarget(delegate, action: #selector(AAPLViewController.cameraButtonDidPress), for: .touchUpInside)
```

How to solve this issue, if I'd like to have multiple clients being targeted by a single button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should work if you make the protocol `@objc`

```
@objc protocol CameraButtonDelegate: class {
    func cameraButtonDidPress(_ sender: UIButton
}
```

and specify the selector as protocol method

```
cameraButtonDidPress.addTarget(delegate, action: #selector(CameraButtonDelegate.cameraButtonDidPress), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: if anyway the implementation will be written inside the class finally , then what is the need for the delegate here

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
cameraButton.addTarget(Service.shared, action: #selector(Service.shared.cameraButtonDidPress(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

//

```
class Service {

   static let shared = Service()

    @objc func cameraButtonDidPress (_ sender:UIButton){


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking for a more elegant solution, avoiding using the singleton.

Comment: Something, similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760481/swift-protocol-as-type-as-target-of-button-action

Comment: if it's a duplicate and solved your problem then delete

Comment: it's not since the Swift syntax has changed significantly and approach described in that answer doesn't work anymore.