# UIViewControllers sharing 'generic' IBAction

Tags: swift, function, viewcontroller, dry, ibaction

I have an app with 6 `UIViewControllers`.

ANY `viewcontroller` features a function like this one:

```
@IBAction func onHelp(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            let helpVC =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Help") as! HelpViewController
            helpVC.starter = "MapHelp"
            helpVC.helpSubtitle = "Map"
            self.present(helpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })

    }
```

Any `IBAction` in any `viewcontroller` presents the same `HelpViewController` but passing different parameters (`starter` and `helpSubtitle`).

Since I don't like to repeat code, first of all I thought this function should be converted to something more generic.

But: is there any way to create a generic `IBAction`, working for every `viewcontroller`?

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem`, isn't that a NavigationController button? What about subclassing the NavigationController, add that method, and on each ViewController, add an protocol extension to retrieve the parameters?

Comment: Why not create a BaseViewController, have all your ViewControllers inherit from that one, Create IBActions in each VC, call the same parent class method from all the children. That way the code is reused, you don't have to write it everywhere and you don't have to worry about creating a generic IBAction. Make the method generic, keep the IBActions separate. You can provide the parameters in the base class method's signature too, which can vary from VC to VC

Comment: Also any reason why you are specifically doing it in the main thread? IBActions are by default performed on the main thread.

Comment: @Larme : yes, it is a Navigation Controller, but, please, could you expand a little? I'm not sure I understood your solution.

Comment: @NSNoob : I tried something very similar but I stopped when I found multiple inheritance was not allowed. Your idea could work, instead. But I'm still creating one IBAction for each controller, right? Finally, to answer your question: the code presents a simple modal, but, I don't now why, when that code is performed without dispatch queue, the modal is not presented immediately

Comment: I have deleted my answer. It would not work really because the protocol method could not be an `@IBAction`.

Comment: @Sulthan : no problem, thanks anyway for taking the time to answer  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a BaseViewController and add the generic method there.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {



override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func genericMethod(starter: String, helpSubtitle: String){
        let helpVC =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Help") as! HelpViewController
        helpVC.starter = starter
        helpVC.helpSubtitle = helpSubtitle
        self.present(helpVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func onHelp(_ sender: UIButton?) {
       //You can use this method as generic IBaction if you want. It can be connected to buttons of all child View Controllers. But doing so will limit your param sending ability. On the plus side though, you won't have to define an IBAction everywhere and you can simply connect your child VC's button to Parent Class' IBAction.
    }

}
```

Now inherit your ViewControllers from this class like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        genericMethod(starter: "View Controller", helpSubtitle: "I was triggered from VC1")
    }

}
```

and

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        genericMethod(starter: "View Controller 2", helpSubtitle: "I was triggered from VC2")
    }

}
```

That's it. Both your ViewControllers can call the parent method. If you still want to use the generic IBAction, you can do that too but I'd not recommend that course given that you want to pass params that can vary. If you wanted to do it though, it would look like this:

[image]

Bear in mind, the ViewController here has been inherited from the base ViewController which is why it can access the IBActions defined in the parent class. All you have to do is drag and connect.

Comment: I like it, but, even after researching, I hoped that something could be done to have a sort of generic IBAction too. Thanks  :-)

Comment: IBAction has nothing to do with "generics" or "generic approach", it is still a function, it's just become visible in IB.

Comment: @Injectios Not sure what gave the impression that I was implying otherwise. If it helps, English is my second language so it is possible that I may not have been clear enough. What I meant by generic was as in a single method that can be used by multiple objects.

Comment: So these objects must be same type/class in IB. Otherwise, if you declare different types/classes then your function is not visible, you can try to use protocols/or inheritance and conform all your view-controllers to protocol where IBAction is declared, never tried though.

Comment: @Injectios If all those objects inherited from the same parent class then yes, it works. Other types won't be able to access it but then again, in OP's scenario, they don't have to. Only the VCs need to access it. So what would be the whole point? As for your other suggestion, OP will have to provide definitions for the method signatures of the protocol in all the VCs, which is precisely what they want to avoid. You could try the route Sulthan took by creating an extension of UIViewController but as he says, protocol methods cannot be  IBActions.

Comment: Why not do that programmatically what you want, without IBAction, check this out - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760481/swift-protocol-as-type-as-target-of-button-action

Comment: @Injectios : NSNoob correctly answered my question based on my real scenario, not an ideal one